# Oracle PL/SQL how do you output how many inserts have been made in a FORALL statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulkinsert, forall

What's the best way of getting and outputting how many rows have been inserted in the FORALL statement I have below. I've seen the SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT but I'm not sure how that would work in the below statement.

is it

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.('rows inserted '||SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT||'');
```

Does the above need to go in another FORALL statement? For the code below how would I achieve this?

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_arc_act_plus_trigger1 IS TABLE OF arc_act_plus_triggers1%ROWTYPE;
  v_arc_act_plus_triggers1 t_arc_act_plus_trigger1;

  CURSOR c_arc_act_plus_triggers1 IS
      SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ apt.*
        FROM act_plus_triggers1 apt
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT 1
                   FROM act_plus_triggers_copy1 aptc
                  WHERE aptc.surr_id = apt.surr_id)
         AND apt.status IN ('EXT', 'EXP');
BEGIN

    OPEN c_arc_act_plus_triggers1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_arc_act_plus_triggers1 BULK COLLECT INTO v_arc_act_plus_triggers1 LIMIT 10000;  -- limit to 10k to avoid out of memory

        FORALL i IN 1..v_arc_act_plus_triggers1.COUNT
        INSERT /*+ APPEND_VALUES */ INTO arc_act_plus_triggers1 values v_arc_act_plus_triggers1(i);  


        Com0932.get_parameter ('ACT_ARCHIVE_TRIGGER_STOP_YN',l_STOP_PROGRAM_YN);         
        IF l_STOP_PROGRAM_YN = 'Y' THEN
            p_location('insert_into_arc_act_plus - STOP_PROGRAM_YN flag = '||l_STOP_PROGRAM_YN||' so ROLLBACK'); 
            ROLLBACK;
            EXIT;
        END IF; 

        -- **************************************************
        -- Output how many records have been inserted here???
        -- **************************************************

        -- commit after every 10000 records into arc_act_plus_triggers1   
        COMMIT;     
        EXIT WHEN c_arc_act_plus_triggers1%NOTFOUND;


    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_arc_act_plus_triggers1;

END;
```

Comment: Did you try `SQL%ROWCOUNT`? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS99956

Comment: Presumably, it'd be `v_arc_act_plus_triggers1.COUNT`? Assuming no exceptions occur, etc.

Comment: No exceptions occur as it's just a straight copy from one table to a archive table which is a copy.

Comment: not sure of SQL%ROWCOUNT works within a FORALL statement? or does it @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you just doing this as a straightforward `insert into ... select ...` statement? It'll be more performant than a bulk collect would be. Actually, thinking about it, maybe a MERGE statement would work best here.

Comment: Hi @Boneist, I understand a insert.... select would be quicker but they've told me that they've had issues with memory/cpu and the length of time the straight insert takes, sometimes it inserts 65,000,000 rows and they want a way of stopping the program if it's running to long in the morning, they can then restart the job the next day. I've added the stop flag to show in code to show what I mean

Comment: I'd still do it as an insert (or merge) and just restrict the number of rows being inserted per loop. E.g. something like: `loop insert into ... select .... where rownum <=10000 and not exists (select ...) ....; exit when sql%rowcount = 0; end loop;`

Comment: And possibly you'd benefit from increasing the number of rows inserted at once (a million rows shouldn't be too strenuous at a time). If it's taking your overnight job several hours to run and memory/cpu issues, what appears to be a simple insert statement, perhaps you ought to look at tuning the insert first. E.g. are the relevant indexes there? Would it benefit from being turned into a merge statement (and therefore losing the not-exists)? And is the parallel hindering rather than helping?

Comment: @ShaunKinnair. Following on from Boneist's comments, I would concur. 65M rows should not be a an issue on a reasonable server/storage. You can employ direct path insert (using the APPEND hint ), together with parallelism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked as I have nothing to test against so please forgive any 'missing semi-colon type errors' and I'm afraid I'm not in a position to performance check this.

Your code seems to select which rows to insert to the archive table based on there non-existence in the archive. Therefore simply use an INSERT based on a SELECT limited by a suitable ROWNUM value. Once you commit then the next time round the loop it wont try getting already archived rows as you just committed them.

I think this should be as quick if not quicker than bulkifying the inserts with the advantage that its simpler - Occams Razor and all that.

```
DECLARE
  l_commit_count NUMBER := 10000;
  l_rows_copied NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Started at '||TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD_MON_YYY HH24:MI:SS');
    LOOP
        INSERT /*+APPEND */
        INTO c_arc_act_plus_triggers1
        SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ apt.*
            FROM act_plus_triggers1 apt
           WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (SELECT 1
                       FROM act_plus_triggers_copy1 aptc
                      WHERE aptc.surr_id = apt.surr_id)
             AND apt.status IN ('EXT', 'EXP')
             AND rownum < l_commit_count;

        COMMIT;         
        l_rows := l_rows + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
        EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT < 1;
    END LOOP        
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Finished at '||TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD_MON_YYY HH24:MI:SS');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(l_rows)||' rows copied to the archive table');
END;
```

Comment: I'll try the above and get back to you